# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error while loggin into eventviewer. I am looging the exception in event viewer as well as rolling flat file. If i remove the eventviewer section then rolling flat file works perfectly, but only when i add this it gives the exception

> {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   \"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter\", name =
>   \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: while resolving.\r\nException
>   is: InvalidOperationException - The type TraceListener cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this
>   value.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
>   time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl,LogWriter.**default**
>   (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,
>   (none))\r\n  Resolving parameter \"structureHolder\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder
>   structureHolder,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider
>   instrumentationProvider,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator
>   updateCoordinator)\r\n    Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,LogWriterStructureHolder.**default**
>   (mapped from
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,
>   (none))\r\n    Resolving parameter \"traceSources\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] filters,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   traceSourceNames,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceSources,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   allEventsTraceSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   notProcessedTraceSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   errorsTraceSource, System.String defaultCategory, System.Boolean
>   tracingEnabled, System.Boolean logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch,
>   System.Boolean revertImpersonation)\r\n      Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,General\r\n
>
>   Resolving parameter \"traceListeners\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource(System.String
>   name,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Diagnostics.TraceListener,
>   System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceListeners,
>   System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels level, System.Boolean autoFlush,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider
>   instrumentationProvider)\r\n        Resolving
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceListener,Event Log Trace Listener\r\n"}

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was due to an error in my configuration file. I referenced trace listeners from my categorySources section which did not exist in my listeners section. I removed the categories and the mappings (i did not use them anyway) and then it worked. I guess you can validate your configuration file in the configuration console and then it will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Make sure you are referencing the correct DLLs

> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
>
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

2 - Make sure your configuration file is in the right location (in the same project or in a references project)

3 - Make sure your configuration file is correct. Editing it with the Enterprise Library Configuration Tool, nothing should be in red. Try expanding all trace listeners, categories, etc. The most common error is that one of the Special Categories is pointing to a non existing Listener.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with ExceptionHanlder., I switched over to using Unity container directly after playing around with intro material re: logging.

I basically just copied the examples from the Help files and briefly wondered why it wasn't working and errored on Type Resolution; Could not resolve.

The answer was simple enough. I had only "played" with logging prior to switching to Unity container but the examples I was using/copying were using both Logging and Exception Handling injection.

Since I hadn't "played: with Exception Handling in 5.0, there were no entries for this in the configuration file, hence the reason why Unity could not resolve.

Solution: take 5 seconds to add the ExceptionHandling block into the config file using the tools and I was good to go and keep on "playing".

Unity needs the entries for each resolved block in the config file even if they are not Named / customised. This is rediculously obvious but easily overlloked if you are hacking away with example code for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because a database listener was set with a connection string that didn't exist.

To help diagnose, comment out the listener lines and then add them again one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when moving the app to another server, and in my case, it was the `initializeData` field, which sets the path for the log file, was not valid, and it was not able to create the log file at startup.
When i edited and put a valid path for the log to be created, it worked ok.
Hope it helps someone.