# "The type LogWriter cannot be constructed." I am used PostSharp And Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, postsharp

[image]

The type LogWriter cannot be constructed.
You must configure the container to supply this value. I have used mvc4 PostSharp and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Stack Trace of the exception I can see that you are using Unity for the implementation of Dependency Injection.

Solution is given in above this post [Unity: The type LogWriter cannot be constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950547/unity-the-type-logwriter-cannot-be-constructed)